# Where should logging logic sit within a DDD solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, domain-driven-design

I've created a custom filter for my MVC application, `[LogAttribute]`. Action methods are decorated with this and it has the responsibility to create a `LogEntry` object to pass into some type of provider - `ILoggerProvider`.

My question is, where should `ILoggerProvider` and it's implementations sit (I'll be wanting to use a DI technology on it)? Should they go in the domain model, the UI project or a separate class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since logging has nothing to do with UI, this is definetly the wrong place.
The domain model is there for data representation in my opinion.
So i would do it in a seperate class or even a seperate project.

I have a MVC application where i have a seperate project for a logging service. In my structure it is in the most bottom layer (data access)  since it directly logs to files and all other services are using it. I also use DI on it with use of the MEF framework.

This has been working fine for me for a while and i didn't want to change it since then.
I had other solutions which i skipped after a while because they were not as elegant to use as my current solution.

Hope that helps you with your decision.

Answer (score 12):

Unless your software's primary function is *Logging* or *Auditing*, it should be an **Infrastructure LoggingService**.

And unless your logging implementation is tightly-coupled with your Domain Objects (I hope it isn't!), I would suggest a completely separate assembly.

Comment: I think this a better idea than the answer marked as the best one

Comment: Agreed, this is a better answer.

Comment: So, being a pure infrastructure service, would the interface and implementation of the Logger be defined at the infrastructure layer?

Answer (score 5):

I'd generally contend that ILoggingProvider should sit within the domain model for a few reasons. From a logistics and sanity perspective, your domain classes probably need to reference the logger. From a DDD perspective, given the world of SOX and such we live in, one can argue that logging is a core domain feature for regulatory compliance.

Now, the implementations can definitely sit off in your infrastructure projects, no need to clutter the model with all that.

Comment: This makes sense, because the regulatory body is imposing constraints on your Ubiquitous Language (UL).  In particular, the regulation that says "Thou shalt log this and that event" has a corresponding entity in your model.  Regulations can be part of the domain, and by virtue the UL, hence the model gets some kind of logging artifact.